# How to make children auto fit parent's width only with CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-float, width, fluid-layout

I have a server-side component that generates a fluid layout "toolbar" using `DIV` without fixed width, generating many `A` inside it.

Then I need customize that layout to make all `A` tags auto fit to the parent width. But the number of children is variable and the parent's width isn't known (it auto fits itself to the window).

I made some tests with this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ErickPetru/6nSEj/1/

But I can't find a way to make it dynamic (uncomment the last `A` tag to see how it ins't working, lol).

I can't change the server-side sources to gerenate HTML with fixed width. And I really would like to solve it only with CSS if there is any way, even that with JavaScript I could achieve that result.

How can I make all the children auto-fit itself to the parent's width independently of the number of children?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can't be done strictly with CSS, so (if I'm right) you have to sprinkle in a bit of JavaScript.

Comment: That was my fear. Maybe CSS3 and HTML5 could do something... Or not?

Comment: If you're willing to drop support for IE7, you do it with CSS easily. [Do you care about IE7?](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201004-201104) A good idea is to do my magical option, with a JavaScript workaround for <=IE7

Comment: @ErickPetru: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work - I'm only here because I happened to look back at this question.

Comment: @thirtydot, supose I don't care about IE7. Can you please answers how can I do it easily only with CSS?

Comment: @ErickPetru: I already did :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is already a pretty old question. Although the answers given attended well at the time, nowadays the [Flexible Box Layout](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/) offers the same result with much more simplicity, with [good support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) in all modern browsers. I strongly recommend it!

```css
/* Important parts */
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.parent a {
  flex: 1;
}

/* Decoration */
.parent {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #ededed;
}

.parent a {
  line-height: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #dbdbdb;
  color: #111;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <a href="#">Some</a>
  <a href="#">Other</a>
  <a href="#">Any</a>
</div>

<br>

<div class="parent">
  <a href="#">Some</a>
  <a href="#">Other</a>
  <a href="#">Any</a>
  <a href="#">One More</a>
  <a href="#">Last</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use `display: table-cell`:

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/6nSEj/12/ *([or with 5 children](http://jsfiddle.net/6nSEj/13/))*

This won't work in IE7 because that browser simply doesn't support `display: table` and friends.

```
div.parent {
    ..
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
div.parent a {
    ..
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Now that IE7 has less than 4% of marketshare (at least here in my country), I believe it is the best choice since it solves the problem only with CSS.

Comment: @thirtydot Dude, this is an epic solution! Extremely useful in many cases. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For now many use jQuery as a solution to this problem. All you need is one line. This is from your fiddle.

```
$("div.parent a").css("width", (($("div.parent").width() / $("div.parent a").length ) -2) + "px");
```