# Which is the better jQuery approach to autofit children on parent DIV width?

Tags: jquery, html, performance, fluid-layout

Based on the answers to another mine question (this: [How to make children auto fit parent's width only with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858108/how-to-make-children-auto-fit-parents-width-only-with-css)), I'm thinking which is the best jQuery approach to solve the problem regarding performance.

*Block 1: find all DOM elements when needed:*

```
$("div.parent a").css("width", $("div.parent").width() / $("div.parent a").length - 2);
```

*Block 2: find only DOM children, use each(), parent() and siblings():*

```
$("div.parent a").each(function() {
    $(this).css("width", $(this).parent().width() / $(this).siblings().length - 2);
});
```

*Block 3: find DOM parent first, use each() and find children based on context:*

```
$("div.parent").each(function() {
    $("a", this).css("width", $(this).width() / $("a", this).length - 2);
});
```

Here is the Fiddle if someone wants to test: http://jsfiddle.net/ErickPetru/6nSEj/3/

**So, which block is better? And why?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would pre-query the elements, like so:

```
// find the elements you want to resize
var $links = $("div.parent a");

// resize them, and use the parent width
$links.width($links.parent().width() / $links.length - 2);
```

This way you're looking up the links, and looking up to the parent, only once. There's no looping, and there's no redundant queries.

Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/xixionia/Gsek5/

Comment: Nice! I updated my Fiddle using your approach. Much more simple. Thanks! http://jsfiddle.net/6nSEj/11/

Answer (score 3):

Using [FireBug profiling](http://getfirebug.com/javascript):

- block 1:  8.466 ms, 372 calls
- block 2: 10.130 ms, 526 calls
- block 3:  8.560 ms, 383 calls

also xixonia's answer was the fastest

- xixonia:  8.205 ms, 369 calls

In order of speed:

1. xixonia's
2. block 1
3. block 3

wouldn't even use block 2

Answer (score 0):

I would say `Block 1` would be best due to the fact that it does **not** require a loop,

You can also try this:

```
$("div.parent a").css({
    width: $(this).parent().width() / $(this).siblings().length - 2)
});
```

Comment: "css({...})" does not change the scope of "this", so $(this) would refer to the jQuery object enclosing the local "this", and not the individual links.

Comment: I think jQuery really could change the scope of `this` for `css()` and many other methods. But [xixonia](http://stackoverflow.com/users/696056/xixonia) is right: doesn't works.