# More CSS woes: how to stack divs inside another div, and have them all behave?

Tags: html, css

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/csaltyj/mbnWm/

```
<style type="text/css">
    #container {
        border: 2px solid #000;
        position: absolute;
        width: 20em;
    }

    .box {
        background: transparent;
        position: absolute;
        border: 1px solid #0f0;
    }
</style>
<div id="container">
    <div class="box">
        <p>X</p>
        <p>Taller than the other two.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Y</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Z</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is not working. They overlap fine, but there are issues. The goal is to:

1. Get the `#container` to properly wrap around the children divs.
2. Have the `.box` divs fill (width & height) the parent `#container` (so the green borders should reach all the way out to the thick black border).

This must be possible, I'm just having a hard time with positioning. (that and floats seem to be the toughest parts of CSS)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: FYI, you aren't `float`ing, you are `position`ing. There's a huge difference.

Comment: @Kevin I know that, just making an aside comment that floats & positioning are two of the most confusing parts of CSS, it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have here is that anything that is `position: absolute;` is removed from flow. Thus, `#container` can never contain the `.box`es. In this cause you will need to set `height` and `width` on `#container` and make sure the `.box`es can never expand beyond it. You requested they fill the `#container`, so I've done that here: http://jsfiddle.net/X3EJ6/

Note though that because `width` and `height` are set to `100%` the borders will not work correctly. You will need to set explicit values or use `box-sizing` and set it to `border-box` (this is not support in IE < 8).

```
<style type="text/css">
    #container {
        border: 2px solid #000;
        position: absolute;
        width: 20em;
        height: 10ex;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .box {
        background: transparent;
        position: absolute;
        border: 1px solid #0f0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
<div id="container">
    <div class="box">
        <p>X</p>
        <p>Taller than the other two.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Y</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Z</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice. Of course, I forgot to mention that I need to not specify a height on anything at all. So I've modified your code and used jQuery to dynamically set the heights to all match the largest item in the container. http://jsfiddle.net/csaltyj/X3EJ6/1/

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack, same issue exists if you want borders to appear inside the parent. You will need to subtract any padding, borders, and margins on `.box` from the `innerWidth` of `#container`

Answer (score 2):

[How to make children auto fit parent's width only with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858108/how-to-make-children-auto-fit-parents-width-only-with-css)

Comment: Ha.. I see we're in the same boat. Bummer.

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack, it's the answer. There you will see how to do it.